# Can I open a downloaded file with js/jquery/vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, asp.net-core, vuejs2

Is it possible to download a file and then automatically open it for the user using javascript, jquery or vue.js?

Comment: No, that would be a massive security risk as just by visiting a website you could download and execute anything you wanted on a users computer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can help you:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/open .

:)

Answer (score 0):

Only filetypes suported by your client's browser.
use iframe to do so.